# Should the question of a Q&A have the same details as if it weren't a Q&A?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

When I immediately answer my own question Q&A style, I'll sometimes move details that would normally go in the question part to the answer part.

[In this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303517/some-netflix-videos-are-showing-horizontal-tearing-flickering-lines) the question doesn't mention that I have a Radeon graphics card, because in the answer give steps to determine if you're using a Radeon graphics card.

I could move the steps for determining if you have a Radeon card to the question section, to make it more resemble asking a question without answering myself, but if I was asking a question without answering myself I'd simply say that I have a Radeon card without saying *how* I determined that.

So what's the best practice here?

Comment: See also: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/21960)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both the question and your answer need to stand on their own.

Without your answer, are there enough details in the question that someone (besides you) could answer it? No? Then you need to fix that or risk getting the answer closed for lacking details.

Self-answering is a great way to share things you've learned, but it also needs a good question. It's entirely possible that someone has an even better solution than you.